# How to version shapefiles

Tags: versioning, blob, dbf, shapefile

The program I work on has several shapefiles, with quite a few attributes. At the moment they are stored in our version control (Subversion) as compressed blobs (dbf.gz, shp.gz and shx.gz). This is how they are used by the program, but it's extremely inconvenient for versioning purposes. We get no information about changes to entries, or attributes - just that something, somewhere in the file has changed. No useful diff.

The DBF is the one that has the attributes. I was thinking maybe we could store it as CSV and then as part of the build process, [convert it to DBF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440791/convert-csv-file-into-dbf-using-python) and do ??? (to be determined) to make it a valid shapefile, then make the zipped version as it currently uses.

Another approach might be to remove nearly all the attributes from the shapefile, store those in CSV/YAML/whatever (which can be versioned nicely), and either look them up by the shape IDs or try to attach them to our objects after they have been instantiated from shapefiles, something like that.

But maybe folks with more experience with shapefiles have better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The DBF you are referring to starting your second paragraph has the attributes.  Why not dump out the table on a "per Shape" basis to an XML style file and use THAT for the subversion.  If you are actually working within Visual Foxpro (which also uses DBF style files too), you could use the function CursorToXML() and just run that through a loop of distinct shapes and dump out to each respective XML file.  Then, when reading it back in.... XMLToCursor() of the per file shape.