# convert csv file to dbf

Tags: python, csv, dbf

i' ve got al lot of csv file and would like to convert them to a dbf file.
I found the code from Ethan Furman (see below)
It works really good - thanks a lot - but my csv files have as the delimiter a semicolon. So with the code python puts all my data into one column, but I've got 5 columns.
How can I change the delimiter?

here the link:
[Convert .csv file into .dbf using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440791/convert-csv-file-into-dbf-using-python)

especially:

> Using the dbf package you can get a basic csv file with code similar to this:
>
> ```
> import dbf
> some_table = dbf.from_csv(csvfile='/path/to/file.csv', to_disk=True)
> ```
>
> This will create table with the same name and either Character or Memo fields and field names of f0, f1, f2, etc.
>
> For a different filename use the `filename` parameter, and if you know your field names you can also use the `field_names` parameter.
>
> ```
> some_table = dbf.from_csv(csvfile='data.csv', filename='mytable',
>         field_names='name age birth'.split())
> ```
>
> Rather basic documentation is available [here](http://packages.python.org/dbf/).

Comment: I'm not sure what code you're referring to. It seems you're missing a few links. I checked the code at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362715-dbf-reader-and-writer/, and it seems to convert from one dbf (Xbase) format to another (binary), not from CSV to dbf. Is that the right code?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the `dbf` code, I don't see any way to pass a dialect, so you may transform your files as follows:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv'), delimiter=';')
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'))
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Note: This will quote properly rows that already contain a comma as part of its contents.

Edit: If you're willing to patch `dbf.from_csv` to accept `delimiter` as a parameter to avoid transforming all your csv files, this should work:

```
--- dbf.py.orig 2012-01-23 12:48:32.112101218 +0100
+++ dbf.py  2012-01-23 12:49:59.468534408 +0100
@@ -4502,13 +4502,14 @@
         print str(table[0])
     finally:
         table.close()
-def from_csv(csvfile, to_disk=False, filename=None, field_names=None, extra_fields=None, dbf_type='db3', memo_size=64, min_field_size=1):
+def from_csv(csvfile, to_disk=False, filename=None, field_names=None, extra_fields=None, dbf_type='db3', memo_size=64, min_field_size=1,
+             delimiter=','):
     """creates a Character table from a csv file
     to_disk will create a table with the same name
     filename will be used if provided
     field_names default to f0, f1, f2, etc, unless specified (list)
     extra_fields can be used to add additional fields -- should be normal field specifiers (list)"""
-    reader = csv.reader(open(csvfile))
+    reader = csv.reader(open(csvfile), delimiter=delimiter)
     if field_names:
         field_names = ['%s M' % fn for fn in field_names]
     else:
```

Comment: Perhaps add 'import csv' just to make it complete

Comment: @JohanLundberg I've added the missing import. Thanks for your feedback.