# Error when trying to convert dbf to csv in Python

Tags: python, dbf

Python newbie here so please be gentle.

I'm trying to convert dbf file to csv. I stumbled upon a [previous, similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440791/convert-csv-file-into-dbf-using-python) question (with opposite conversion though) and was thinking abou using [dbf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/) module.

Using example from the [docs](http://packages.python.org/dbf/) I tried this code:

```
import dbf

dbf_fn = r'_PATH_HERE_\dbffile.dbf'
csv_fn = r'_PATH_HERE_\csvfile.csv'

in_db = dbf.Table(dbf_fn)

in_db.export(filename=csv_fn, header=True)
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    in_db.export(filename=csv_fn, header=True)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\dbf.py", line 3379, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Db3Table' object has no attribute 'export'
```

Why does the export fail?

---

**Update:**

As suggested by [chm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292791/chm) I now use:

```
dbf.export(in_db, csv_fn, header=True)
```

This still causes problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Data_RP\data\projects\kN\GIS\python\04_convert_dbf_ALT.py", line 31, in <module>
    dbf.export(in_db, filename=csv_fn, header=True)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\dbf.py", line 5670, in export
    table = source_table(table_or_records[0])
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\dbf.py", line 3384, in __getitem__
    return self._table[value]
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\dbf.py", line 3175, in __getitem__
    raise DbfError("%s is closed; record %d is unavailable" % (meta.filename, index))
DbfError: D:\Data_RP\data\projects\kN\GIS\shapes\SWM_4N.dbf is closed; record 0 is unavailable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that the doc on the site is wrong.If you use help in your code,you can see the right doc as below:

```
export(table_or_records, filename, field_names=None,
format='csv', header=True, codepage=None)
writes the records using CSV or tab-delimited format, using the filename
given if specified, otherwise the table name
if table_or_records is a collection of records (not an actual table) they
should all be of the same format
```

1.`export` now is not a member of class `Table`.
Just use 
`dbf.export(in_db, csv_fn,  header=True)` 
instead of 
`in_db.export(filename=csv_fn, header=True)`

2.use `open` after create table (code sample:)

```
import dbf

csv_fn = r'sdv.csv'

table = dbf.Table('temptable.dbf')
table.open()

dat=('John Doe', 31)
table.append(dat)
dbf.export(table, csv_fn, header = True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your suggestion. Unfortunately ran into another problem: `DbfError: D:\Data_RP\data\projects\kN\GIS\shapes\SWM_4N.dbf is closed; record 0 is unavailable`. What is the issue now? o_O

Comment: I suggest carefully reading relative docs when faced with problems.Best regards!